# Fotolia - Legal right to alter images

Tags: stock-images

I searched the terms of use on Fotolia and I didn't see anything that said I can't alter the images after I buy them.

For example, if I buy a photo of a man, can I add some facial hair, change the background, ect... and still have the right to publish the image?

Comment: Seems like this should be an email to fotolia, rather than a question on GDSE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question for a specific product and not really about graphic design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter the images.

From both Fotolia's [Standard License](https://en.fotolia.com/Info/Agreements/StandardLicense) and [Extended License](https://en.fotolia.com/Info/Agreements/ExtendedLicense) (emphasis mine):

> Subject to your compliance with the terms of this Agreement, we hereby grant you a non-exclusive, perpetual, worldwide, non-sublicensable, non-transferable license to use, reproduce, **modify** or display the Work...

The licenses also list all restrictions and anything else you need to know—as should the license text for *any* stock images you purchase.

Comment: I just add. You can not resell your finished work. But publish yes. That was probably the point on purchasing the image in the first place.